# Add value with groupByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have some troubles with `groupByKey` in scala and Spark.
I have 2 case classes :

```
case class Employee(id_employee: Long, name_emp: String, salary: String)
```

For the moment I use this 2nd case class:

```
case class Company(id_company: Long, employee:Seq[Employee])
```

However, I want to replace it with this new one:

```
case class Company(id_company: Long, name_comp: String employee:Seq[Employee])
```

There is a parent DataSet (df1) that I use with `groupByKey` to create `Company` objects :

```
val companies = df1.groupByKey(v => v.id_company)
.mapGroups(
  {
    case(k,iter) => Company(k, iter.map(x => Employee(x.id_employee, x.name_emp, x.salary)).toSeq)
  }
).collect()
```

This code works, it returns objects like this one :

```
Company(1234,List(Employee(0987, John, 30000),Employee(4567, Bob, 50000)))
```

But I don't find the tip to add the Company name_comp to those objects (this field exist df1). In order to retrieve objects like this (using the new case class):

```
Company(1234, NYTimes, List(Employee(0987, John, 30000),Employee(4567, Bob, 50000)))
```

Comment: df1 is a relational DataSet :
case class RelType(id_company:Long, name_comp :String, id_employee : Long,  name_emp : String , salary : Int)
But companies is a DataSet[Company]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want both the company id and name, what you can do is to use a tuple as the key when you group your data. This will make both values easily available when constructing the `Company` class:

```
df1.groupByKey(v => (v.id_company, v.name_comp))
  .mapGroups{ case((id, name), iter) => 
    Company(id, name, iter.map(x => Employee(x.id_employee, x.name_emp, x.salary)).toSeq)}
  .collect()
```